# Оптимизация условного ветвления

Tags: python, оптимизация, if

Есть код:

```
def Vybor(x):
    if x == 1:
        print("нечто")
        a()
    elif x == 2:
        print("что-то")
        b()
    elif x == 3:
        print("неизвестно что")
        с()
```

Возможно ли этот "код" (это просто пример типичного кода с ветвлением) сделать более "питонским", оптимизировать его (например, с использованием словарей и т. п.)?

Comment: `print(["нечто", "что-то", "неизвестно что"][x - 1])`.

Comment: `[a, b, c][x - 1]()`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, а если x будет не "1, 2, 3", а, скажем, "qwerty, asdfg, zxcvb"?

Comment: тогда словарь..

Comment: А вы сами поэкспериментируйте, начиная с какого размера словарь будет эффективней последовательности if-ов (в предположении, что все исходы равновероятны)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def vybor(x):
    options = {
        1: "нечто",
        2: "что-то", 
        3: "неизвестно что",
    }
    
    if x in options:
        print(options[x])
    else:
        print("Неправильный параметр.")
```

---

*Примечание:*

Я изменил имя функции `Vybor` на `vybor`, чтобы оно состояло только из строчных букв, в соответствии с [PEP 8 - руководством по написанию кода на Python](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html#section-26):

> Имена функций
>
> Имена функций должны состоять из маленьких букв, а слова разделяться
> символами подчеркивания — это необходимо, чтобы увеличить
> читабельность.

Comment: Если сделать обращение через get, возможно обработать случай, которого нет в словаре. Это будет аккуратнее - чем проверять вхождение ключа

Comment: @Exord - *«Это будет аккуратнее...»*: Я намеренно исключил этот вариант, чтобы мой ответ был понятен большему количеству людей. (Для таких, как вы, не будет проблемой изменить его таким образом, как вы рекомендуете.)

Comment: Да, я понимаю. Я написал этот комментарий не в формате претензии к вашему ответу. А что бы указать что существует такая возможность :)

Answer (score 4):

С версии **python 3.10** возможно использовать `match case` конструкцию.

```
def select(x):
    match x:
        case 1:
            print("нечто")
        case 2:
            print('что-то')
        case 3:
            print('неизвестно что')
        case _:
            print('А такого мы не ожидали')

select(2)
```

вывод:

```
что-то
```

`case _` используется, для любых других значений, не подходящих под паттерн.

Answer (score 2):

Дополню ответ **@MarianD**, и добавлю, как можно сделать ещё и вызов нужной функции:

```py
def vybor(x):
    options = {
        1: ("нечто", a),  # значения теперь не строки, а кортежи вида (строка, функция)
        2: ("что-то", b),   # обратите внимание - скобки после имени функции ставить не нужно
        3: ("неизвестно что", c),
    }
    
    option = options[x]
    print(option[0])  # печатаем нужную строку
    option[1]()  # вызываем нужную функцию
```